# HTTP Get Request in C++

Tags: c++, http, get

I need to sent a HTTP GET Request to my site and then get the contents of the page and parse it. I'de prefer to not use libraries like libCURL because I want the end application to be fully independent (This is quoting from personal experience, I may be wrong but if I recall the client has to have certain Dynamic Link Libraries to run applications with libCURL libraries.), I'm using C++ in Visual Studio 2012.

Code examples would also be good.

Comment: Are you asking how to use winsock2 ?

Comment: Open a socket(), send() your request, recv() your answer.. What have you tried already? Where are you stuck? How can we help you?

Comment: You can always statically link libcurl instead of dynamically linking it if you don't want to deal with distributing DLLs.

Comment: You want to use libCurl. Doing HTTP request may seem trivial if it works but if you diverge from normal by any amount the shit starts to happen very quickly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you don't want to use an external library, you will have to implement HTTP yourself. When you only need the basic functionality (direct download of a file, no redirects, no proxies, no cookies, no authentication, no encryption, no compression, no other shenanigans), this isn't even that hard.

Create a socket, connect it to port 80 of your webserver, and send the following strings to the server:

```
"GET /example.html HTTP/1.1\r\n"
"Host: www.example.com\r\n"
"\r\n"
```

This requests the file www.example.com/example.html from the server you connected to.

The server will respond with an own HTTP response header followed by the data (or an error description).

Answer (score 3):

1. Most libraries can be compiled statically. When you use a static library it gets linked in into your executable and you do not have to ship the library's dll. Maybe this would help: [Walkthrough: Creating and Using a Static Library (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms235627.aspx)
2. Some libraries can be header-only or used in a header-only mode: compiler pulls the library into your source. Again, no dll is generated for the library. For example, you can try [getting Asio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5089464/257568) and [cpp-netlib](https://github.com/cpp-netlib/cpp-netlib) to work in a header-only mode for you. There is also a sampe of a simple http client just for the Asio lying somewhere.
3. I **think** you can use [WinINet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385331) or [WinHTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384273) without shipping any DLLs.

Comment: The WinInet/WinHTTP DLLs are already installed in the OS.  You do not need to deploy the DLLs yourself, but they are still DLLs nontheless.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code for a GET request in C++

```cpp
std::string GET(std::string url) {
    std::string cmd = "curl -s " + url;
    FILE *p = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");
    char buffer[2];
    std::string body;
    if (!p) {
        return "Error";
    }
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), p)) {
        body += buffer;
    }
    return body;
}
```

Using:

```cpp
std::string response = GET("https://example.com");
// Do actions with response
```

Good luck!

Comment: Useful, but note that this doesn't make an HTTP request in C++ as advertised, it runs `curl` as subprocess which makes the HTTP request. OP says: "I'd prefer to not use libraries like libCURL because I want the end application to be fully independent".