# C++ HTTP request

Tags: c++, http, request

I've been searching quite sometime now about HTTP requests, but can't get anywhere because of only partially explained forums' answers. The most helpful I've seen so far is from stackoverflow:
[http-get-request-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004550/http-get-request-in-c)
From what I can tell, there's no way of doing it easily without an external library. Could anyone help with HTTP request in general and connection of the program with the internet? Maybe post a link of where you first saw it?

Comment: "there's no way of doing it easily without an external library" — That's because external libraries exist to make complicated things easy.

Comment: If you are trying to avoid external libraries, what is your problem? Opening a socket? Formatting the HTTP request? A complete guide to creating network connections and HTTP is rather too broad a topic for Stackoverflow.

Comment: Basic start is too broad? I doubt it.

Comment: What you really want to do? If is learning the protocol, you should look for [HTTP protocol specs](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) (not easy to read though).

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to do http in C++, for me, has been using **Boost.Asio**. It's an external library that takes in charge the connection server/client.

You should look at their c++ examples/tutorial: [HTTP Client, HTTP Server, HTTP Server 2, HTTP Server 3, HTTP Server 4](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html). You can see there some examples of **http** communication **client-side** and **server-side**.

**Boost Library** is really close to C++. It can look afrightening at first sight, but it's really worth the effort of learning.

Comment: Boost is huge pile of libraries. Those are sometimes even recreating similar things instead of using other parts of boost. asio is great however.

Comment: @ÖöTiib the book **Beyond the C++ Standard Library: An Introduction to Boost** has helped me stayed focussed on what seems to be the most important and useful libraries. Not dwelled that much on other libraries for the moment.