# Build boost asio 1.58 for windows phone 8.1 & windows 8.1

Tags: boost, boost-asio, boost-regex

I had try to build Boost Asio 1.58 for Windows Phone 8.1 & Windows 8.1 with that command b2

> b2 toolset=msvc=12.0 windows-api=store architecture=arm

but it's fail on build "libboost_regex-vc120-mt-1_58.lib", so i must need "libboost_regex-vc120-mt-1_58.lib" .

The log say error!

> libs\regex\build..\src\fileiter.cpp(102) : error C3861: 'CreateFileA': identifier not found
>   libs\regex\build..\src\fileiter.cpp(106) : error C3861: 'CreateFileMapping': identifier not found
>   libs\regex\build..\src\fileiter.cpp(115) : error C3861: 'MapViewOfFile': identifier not found
>   libs\regex\build..\src\fileiter.cpp(124) : error C3861: 'GetFileSize': identifier not found
>   libs\regex\build..\src\fileiter.cpp(141) : error C3861: 'UnmapViewOfFile': identifier not found
>   libs\regex\build..\src\fileiter.cpp(383) : error C3861: 'FindFirstFileA': identifier not found

So anyone can help me fix it ? Thanks :)

Comment: You could use the header-only version if you do not need regex, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089245/boost-asio-as-header-only

Comment: I need use regex for tcp connection in my game. So have any solution here.

Comment: what is the relationship between tcp and regex?

Comment: In Win_32 project , if i try to remove regex the project not working, and if had regex it working good. But i can't build library of regex for WP 8.1 or Win 8.1 .

Comment: So, use Boost.Spirit instead of regex. You'll only benefit from it.

Comment: I don't use Boost.Regex for processing string or anything else. I only use  Network to make a TCP client  inside Boost Asio .

Comment: Boost.Asio depends on regex only if you use `read_until` or [`async_read_until` overloads that use `boost::regex` parameter](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/using.html). Just do not use these functions!

Comment: Ya. I don't use read_until or async_read_until , but i don't know how to remove regex, when i compile it's always show error "libboost_regex-vc120-mt-1_58.lib can't open" :(

Answer (score 0):

Go to C++ -> Preprocessor -> Add "BOOST_REGEX_NO_LIB" for disable auto linking Boost.Regex