# Is it possible to use Boost serialization as a header only library?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization, header-only

Below is a minimal example to use the great [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) library.

To compile the library I need to link with the `boost_serialization` precompiled library.

```
$ c++ -std=c++11 example.cpp -o example.x -lboost_serialization
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The library is heavily templated an although complicated internally the actual code (function body) is quite simple. There are only a few references that need the linking, namely:

```
boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::text_oarchive_impl(std::ostream&, unsigned int)
boost::archive::text_iarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_iarchive>::text_iarchive_impl(std::istream&, unsigned int)
boost::archive::text_iarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::~text_oarchive_impl()
boost::archive::text_iarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_iarchive>::~text_iarchive_impl()
...
boost::archive::archive_exception::~archive_exception()'
```

**Is there a chance that the library can be used without linking as a header-only library?**

For example some undocumented trick or hack?

That would make it more simple to use in some supercomputer clusters and environments where it is not that simply to compile Boost.

```
#include<sstream>
#include<numeric>
#include<boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp> // needs linking 
#include<boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include<boost/serialization/vector.hpp>

int main(){

    std::vector<double> v(10); std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
    std::stringstream ss;
    {
        boost::archive::text_oarchive toa(ss);
        toa << v;
    }
    std::vector<double> v2;
    boost::archive::text_iarchive tia(ss);
    tia >> v2;
    assert(v == v2);
}
```

---

**EDIT**: I would be very cool if the library gave the option to be header only, like Boost.Asio does (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40729439/225186.)

---

**EDIT2**: The author and maintainer of Boost.Serialization rejected the idea of making it header only. https://github.com/boostorg/serialization/issues/71

Comment: > environments where it is not that simply to compile Boost. - you have to compile your program somewhere.. why not compile boost there too?  Anyhow, you can always just try #include'ing the cpp files and see what happens.  but isn't that an awful lot like compiling boost?

Comment: I tried `#include`ing `.cpp` files. I was able to make it work in some simple cases but not for the example above. I start getting `error: redefinition of ‘class boost::archive::detail::extra_detail::map<Archive>’` (as expect, including cpps becomes a mess very quickly)

Comment: This is something I have wanted for years. If any Boost library ought to be header-only, `serialization` is it. But it's not, so I wound up rolling my own

Comment: @Nemo, your own serialization library? Or your own patches to Boost serialization?

Comment: My own serialization library. It was partly an exercise to teach myself template meta-programming and partly because I needed it.

Comment: @Nemo, yes, it is not that hard to implement. The hard part, if one wants it, is to the automatic tracking of pointers (and smart pointers) and versioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up including the cpp sources from a certain version of Boost Serialization.
I chose the cpp files by trial and error.

https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-mpi3/-/tree/master/include/mpi3/serialization_hack

[image: serialiation_hack]

Basically, I include these cpp files from the same place I would include the Serialization hpp files.

```
#include <boost/archive/detail/common_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/detail/common_oarchive.hpp>

#include <boost/archive/archive_exception.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/basic_streambuf_locale_saver.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/detail/auto_link_archive.hpp>
//#include <boost/archive/detail/abi_prefix.hpp> // must be the last header

#include <boost/serialization/array.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/is_bitwise_serializable.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/item_version_type.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>

#include <boost/mpl/placeholders.hpp>

#include <any>
#include <optional>

// use this to avoid need for linking -lserialization
#ifdef _MAKE_BOOST_SERIALIZATION_HEADER_ONLY
//#include <boost/archive/detail/decl.hpp>
#if BOOST_VERSION > 106000 && BOOST_VERSION < 106600
#include "../mpi3/serialization_hack/singleton.cpp"
#endif
#if BOOST_VERSION < 105900
#define BOOST_ARCHIVE_DECL
#define BOOST_SERIALIZATION_DECL
#endif
// NOLINTBEGIN(hicpp-use-auto,modernize-use-auto)  external code
#include "../mpi3/serialization_hack/archive_exception.cpp"  // NOLINT(bugprone-suspicious-include) hack
#include "../mpi3/serialization_hack/basic_archive.cpp"  // NOLINT(bugprone-suspicious-include) hack
#include "../mpi3/serialization_hack/basic_iarchive.cpp"  // NOLINT(bugprone-suspicious-include) hack
#include "../mpi3/serialization_hack/basic_iserializer.cpp"  // NOLINT(bugprone-suspicious-include) hack
#include "../mpi3/serialization_hack/basic_oarchive.cpp"  // NOLINT(bugprone-suspicious-include) hack
#include "../mpi3/serialization_hack/basic_oserializer.cpp"  // NOLINT(bugprone-suspicious-include) hack
#include "../mpi3/serialization_hack/extended_type_info.cpp"  // NOLINT(bugprone-suspicious-include) hack
#include "../mpi3/serialization_hack/extended_type_info_typeid.cpp"  // NOLINT(bugprone-suspicious-include) hack
// NOLINTEND(hicpp-use-auto,modernize-use-auto)
```

A problem with this approach is that I had to modify the sources to accommodate different versions of Boost.Serialization and also had to do some modification to appease compiler warnings and static analyzers.